# Learning Specific Topics In Machine Learning

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I am a beginner in machine learning and I already have a good linear algebra/calculus background.

I am interested in being able to eventually understand and implement convolutional neural networks, feature-based classifiers, and boosting algorithms. Where should I start, and what steps should I take to reach my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just jump in and fill gaps in your background knowledge when you find them. If you try to learn all the prerequisites first, you'll just end up in a never-ending rabbit-hole of learning the prerequisites to the prerequisites to the prerequisites to the prerequisites.

Answer (score 2):

First I'll say, because you didn't mention it, that you also need a strong probability and statistics background.

A good place to start with CNNs is (in my opinion) the highly praised Stanford course:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv

If you are looking for more practical stuff (and on more than just CNNs), there are many guides for different machine learning models in Kaggle, where you can also join challenges which you can learn a lot from.
https://www.kaggle.com/

If you are interested in theory, this book might help - but might also be difficult without a strong statistical background:
http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/index.html
(the book is free to download from there)

Comment: Advice taken, thank you so much!